# can't get GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete component displayed on to of my react-leaflet Map component

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-leaflet

I am trying to use GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete in order to get coordinates by address and thus center my displayed map accordingly.
I am using react, react-leaflet and leaflet.
The GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete component works fine on its own, but I want it to show on top of the Map rather than just by itself.
I tried putting the component inside the Map component like so:

```
<Map>
    <GeoapifyContext>
      <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete>
      </GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete>
    </GeoapifyContext>
    <Marker> </Marker> 
<Map>
```

I can see the Marker but not the search box
if I do:

```
<GeoapifyContext>
    <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete>
    </GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete>
</GeoapifyContext>
<Map>
  <Marker> </Marker> 
<Map>
```

I can see the search box above the Map but when I start to type something, I can't see the suggested options.
What am I missing here?
Thanks for any help

Comment: if I use the first method, the search box is actually there but hidden behind the map. If I zoom out I can see the component for a fraction of a second. How do I make it to display on top of the map?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to show the behaviour?